# Reading from a concurrent function via channel using goroutine and a closure giving error

Tags: go, synchronization, closures, channel, goroutine

I have a function (not a closure) that is writing to a channel. I am invoking that function from a goroutine as

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
wg.Add(1)
go DoStuff(somechan, &wg)
```

Inside DoStuff, I have something like

```
for ; ; {

    if err == io.EOF { 
        fmt.Println(err)
        close(somechan)
        fmt.Println("Closed channel")
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    somechan <- Somefunc()
}
```

Now I am trying to read from that channel using another goroutine.

```
wgread.Add(1)
go func() {
    for ; ; {
        select {
        case chanoutput, ok := <-somechan:
            if ok == true {
                fmt.Println(string(*chanoutput))
            } else {
                fmt.Println("DONE")
                fmt.Println(ok)
                wgread.Done()
                break
            }
        }

    }
}()
wgread.Wait()
```

However, when running, I am getting

```
panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter
```

after printing

```
DONE
false
DONE
false
```

If I give   wgread.Add(2), it will print the above DONE and false 3 times.

Why is is giving a negative waitgroup counter error though I incremented the waitgroup delta by 1? What is the best way to read from a goroutine using another concurrent function or a closure?

Comment: there's not enough of your code here to tell the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The break statement breaks out of the inner most case, for or switch statement.  The function that receives on `somechan` spins in a loop decrementing the wait group when the channel closes.  Write the code like this:

```
wgread.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wgread.Done()
    for chanoutput := range somechan {
        fmt.Println(string(*chanoutput))
    }
    fmt.Println("DONE")
}()
wgread.Wait()
```

If the receiving code is as written in the question, then the receiving goroutine can eliminated. Replace the code from `wgread.Add(1)` to `wgread.Wait()` with

```
for chanoutput := range somechan {
    fmt.Println(string(*chanoutput))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `break` doesn't break the outer `for` loop.
To reference the outer loop, you can use a label like this:

```
Loop:
    for {
        select {
            case ...:
                break Loop
        }
    }
```

Also to help with the coding style,
you should practice using [gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/) to format your code. It will for example replace `for ; ; { ... }` with the cleaner `for { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you @Baloo, but with break Loop, the main thread is waiting now.